# Craft requires MySQL 5.1, got 5.1.73 and an error

Tags: database, requirements

I just moved my website on my production environment, and when I try to login, I get the "MySQL 5.1.0 is required..."

So I did a `phpinfo()` and got `Client API version  5.1.73` for MySQL.
[image]

What did I do wrong ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's the client version. Is the server also running the same version?

Comment: Yes, i just contacted my hosting service , which confirmed "Server Version: 5.1.73-log"

Comment: Run this SQL query against the database and see what version it returns: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`